# IDEA cannot compile java file in gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am build a gradle project and run `compileJava` task everything is ok. But i right click one java file and 'Compile xxxx.java', i get some error.

```
Error:(3, 25) java: package com.jpf.ms.entity not exists
...
```

IDEA version: 14.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `settings.build` references that package, and refresh your dependencies as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017971/intellij-not-pulling-in-grails-3-private-dependencies/36097364#36097364) before running gradle tasks.